# Nginx: How to divert Googlebot traffic to Varnish

Tags: php, nginx, varnish

In Nginx, how can I proxy Googlebot traffic to a Varnish backend, while keeping all other traffic directed at my PHP backend?

I'd like something like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
if ($http_user_agent ~* Googlebot) {
    proxy_pass http://varnish;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

However, the above doesn't work in `server` context because `proxy_pass` is not allowed in a `server` context.

If I wrap the above in a `location / {}` block, then I have an `if` inside a `location` block which makes the `if` [evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). (I tried it and it worked sometimes, but it was intermittent and unpredictable.)

Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use error pages to internally route traffic to a different location in the server block, and then use that location block to proxy to varnish.

example:

```
server {
    error_page 519 = @google;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* Googlebot) {
        return 519;
}
    location @google {
         proxy_pass http://varnish;
}
```

Comment: That would work although better to use "419" as this is not allocated for any other legitimate error.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help